# `continue` in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash

I was trying to find the folders in my music collection that do not contain any mp3 files (some have only album art, or playlists and the like). So I had something like this in a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for DIR in *
do
        [[ -d "${DIR}" ]] || continue
        cd "${DIR}"

        ls *.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]
        then
                echo $DIR has no MP3 files!
                continue
        fi

        cd ..
done
```

Yet, even though there are many folders to go through, this script only checks the first one before exiting... why is this? It's as though the `continue` inside the `if` is breaking out of the loop entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *continue* statement inside the *if* block is the source of your problem:

If no MP3 files were found, `cd ..` doesn't get executed and the acondition `[[ -d "${DIR}" ]]` will most likely fail for all remaining directories.

Comment: Yup! You were exactly right! Can't believe I didn't catch that earlier. Thank you :)